# What to do after deleting a million records

Tags: sql-server-2008, delete

We are implementing a new feature in our system that will cause about a million records (each record is tiny, basically a GUID, a date, and four `smallint` fields) to be purged from a table every night. Basically it's a caching table, and once the data is 7 days old we do:

`DELETE FROM scheduleCache WHERE schDateCreated < '2013-08-26`

This will run every night at 1am, and will purge about a million records every time it runs.

Is there anything I should be noting or doing for a table like this? Any properties I should put on the table, or any routines I should run regularly to "clean up"? I've never dealt with a table like this before.

The table has a single clustered index (GUID + one of the `smallint` fields), and we have a weekly index rebuild that runs Sunday mornings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem of deleting large portions of a table is far from a trivial problem. The best approach, by far, is partitioning. A daily partition scheme with a sliding window is really a magic bullet for this problem, see [How to Implement an Automatic Sliding Window in a Partitioned Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

If you cannot afford partitioning (eg. non-enterprise license on site) then I would recommend clustering by `schDateCreated`. If you need primary key on the GUID+smallint then move it to non-clustered. Delete in batches (eg. `TOP 10000`), in a loop, to reduce pressure on the log. Consider updating stats after the operation.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't afford partitioning, nor can we request our customer-site installations to pay a that size of upgrade just to keep this function working smoothly. I will start it with the clustered index like you suggest and see how we go from there.

Comment: Just as followup, I made a clustered index on the date field, did a `DELETE TOP 10000 WHILE COUNT() > 0` and it's been working great for several months.

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to store the data in one table per day, dropping the tables as they age out of the cache. The tables would have names like cache_(julian date).

Another solution would be to have a set of tables cache_0 to cache_n, truncating each table before you use it. You would use table cache_((julian date) modulo (cycle period)) for each day.

You would need to handle year end carefully, as you'll either go from 365 or 366 to 0 for either solution.

Comment: Indeed, these two things should work, however I'd like to avoid having multiple tables for a) execution plan caching and b) I know some customers do not give the application `create table` permission